# Calculate $\sin\frac{\pi}{16}$ from given trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

There is the choice between four trigonometric identities
$$\sin(4\phi)=8\cos^{3}(\phi)\sin(\phi)-4\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)$$
$$\cos(4\phi)=8\cos^{4}(\phi) -8\cos^{2}(\phi)+1$$
$$\sin^{4}(\phi)=1/8(\cos(4\phi) -4\cos(2\phi)+3)$$
$$\cos^{4}(\phi)=1/8(\cos(4\phi)+4\cos(2\phi)+3)$$
to calculate $\sin\frac{\pi}{16}$. When using the first I got stuck trying to eliminate cos expressions and bring $\sin(4\phi)$ and $\sin(\phi)$ on different sides of the equation, as in
$$\sin(4\phi)=\sin (2\phi)(2-4\sin^{2}(\phi))$$
What way to go ?

Comment: Fun related reading: J. Matthew H. Peters, [*Some trigonometric ratios in surd form*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615517), **Mathematical Gazette** 66 #438 (December 1982), 296-299 ***AND*** Ron Knott's web page [Exact Trigonometric Function Values](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html).

Comment: Just use three times the bisection formulas $\sin\frac{x}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}$, $\cos\frac{x}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\cos(\pi/4) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, Use the second one of your list and put $y = \cos^2(\pi/16)$ to get a quadratic equation in $y$, and then use the identity $\sin(\pi/16) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(\pi/16)}= \sqrt{1-y}$ to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Use the second identity:

$$ 8\cos^4\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right) - 8\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right) + 1 = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt2}{2} $$

Let $x = \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)$ then

$$ 8x^2-8x = \frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2} $$

Completing the square:
$$ 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{4}+1 = \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4} $$

$$ (2x-1)^2 = \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4} $$

Note that $2x-1 = 2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right)-1 = \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) > 0$ so we take the positive root

$$ 2x-1 = \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2} $$

$$ x = \frac{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{4} $$

Then we have

$$ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{16}\right) = \sqrt{1-x} = \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2} $$